# what do I get when I call pathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResourceLoader().getClassloader().getResourece("")

Tags: java, spring, classloader

when I call `pathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResourceLoader().getClassloader().getResourece("")`
I get this:

```
Enumeration<URL> founds
```

then call `founds.nextElement();` , and get this

```
/path/build/resources/main/
/path/build/classes/main/
```

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClassLoader.getResources()` is supposed to give you URLs to all resources matching the name specified. For example, if your classloader's classpath is configured with a couple of binary directories that have equally named packages containing equally named resources in each of them, it will produce 2 URLs pointing to these resources, when you request such a resource from `getResources()`.

Likewise, passing an empty string is interpreted as a topmost level resource. So you are getting a collection of roots to your classpath entries. This is how many classpath scanning facilities set up their search base (mainly in case of `URLClassLoader`s configured with filesystem-based classpath entries).

Be aware that there is a limitation in the `ClassLoader.getResources("")`: in case of empty string passed, it will discard all jar files classpath entries, keeping only expanded binary directories.